# Java BitSet: finding all the true bits efficiently?

Tags: java, performance, memory, bitset

Suppose the `BitSet` from [`java.util.BitSet;`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) is used. The objective is to quickly find all the bit values that are set to `true`. These values are not in order and without a particular pattern. The maximum index of the `BitSet` will be `2^31 - 48`. The total number of bits that will be set to `true` is `(2^31 - 48)/2`. In other words, there are two billion bits that can be `true`/`false`, how can I find all the `true` bits efficiently?

Each time a bit is set to `true`, a run is required to visit all the `true` bits in the `BitSet`. You can see why looping through all the `2^31 - 48` bits every time isn't as efficient when it comes to performance.

Here is a solution that **doesn't** fit my need: create an `int[] indices` of size `(2^31 - 48)/2` and every time a bit `i` is set to `true`, store the value `i` in the next available slot in `indices`. While this helps in achieving the request, it would add about `32 * (2^31 - 48)/2` bits into memory which is around **4.3Gb**.

The focus in on performance and repetitive computation. Using input/output files or something other than `BitSet` is not desired.

What is the fastest approach to achieve the desired behaviour? Or... what is a sufficiently quick approach that also uses significantly less memory?

Comment: Wait... so you're saying that the chance of setting a true/false to the 'Collection' is 50/50, AND you want this done MORE EFFICIENTLY than either counting or storing the positive indices? Maybe use compression like LZW and then disassemble the bits in the dictionary and their locations, but this is a really far shot... and you want 0/0 errors, so any other statistical or analytic trick would be out of the question... "Each time a bit is set to true, a run is required to visit all the true bits"... why? I think here lies the center of the problem...

Comment: Extending on your solution (`int[] indices`): instead of using absolute addresses, you could store the index-delta to the next index as a byte, or depending on the propability, on even less bits. And if it so happens that the delta is bigger than what you can store, have an indicator value that indicates a bigger jump and needs more data read, basically like UTF-8 does bytes-to-char conversions.

Comment: The 1.8 java BitSet has `stream` which produces the objective - have you looked at its implementation?  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#stream--

Answer (score 0):

> What is the fastest approach to achieve the desired behaviour?

If you are restricting yourself to the BitSet API, then I think you need a loop that repeatedly calls `BitSet.nextSetBit`.  Yes, that is going to entail 2^30 calls.  But I think it as good as you are going to get using the `BitSet` API.

If you want something faster you will either need to invent your own data structure to do this (and I don't have any really good ideas), or **change the problem**.

Observation: examining 2^30 bits each time one bit changes is going to be massively computationally expensive no matter how you do it.

If this was my problem, I would *first* look for a smarter solution that avoided having to do that at all.  If there was no smart solution, I would probably use an array of `int` instead of a `BitSet` and figure out a way to parallelize the scan across 8 / 16 / 32 cores<sup>1</sup>.  (But it also depends what you need to do for each bit that is `true`.)

---

<sup>1 - This assumes that you have idle cores / power / cooling to throw at this problem.</sup>

---

> Or... what is a sufficiently quick approach that also uses significantly less memory?

AFAIK, you can't represent `2^N` random true / false values in better that `O(2^N)` bits.  Your only hope would be if the bit pattern was non-random and easily compressible.  And even then you have the problems of the CPU cost of compression / decompression, and the problem of efficiently updating a bit in the compressed bit sequence.  Whether this is feasible would depend on the nature of your bit stream.

Comment: Why do you think that parallelizing the processing of an int array is better than just parallelizing the processing of the bitset?

Comment: Hmm ...  now that you mention it, I don't have a good answer to that.